# Reading a txt file into a list without newlines in python

Tags: python, list, txt

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
FSDAF  
HKLWF  
AAKEP
```

How can I read that into a list so it looks like this:
lst = ['FSDAF', 'HKLWF', 'AAKEP']
I did something like this but I cant get rid of the newlines:

```
file = open('dane.txt', 'r')
lst = file.readlines()
```

And it displays the newlines like this:

```
['FSDAF\n', 'HKLWF\n', 'AAKEP\n']
```

Comment: with open("dane.txt", "r") as fp: data = [line.rstrip() for line in fp]; print(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.rstrip()`:

```py
data = ['FSDAF\n', 'HKLWF\n', 'AAKEP\n']
print([line.rstrip() for line in data])
```

Comment: @low_ratio, actually this is a better answer. +1

Comment: rstrip() removes all tailing blank space. Better solution is rstrip('\n')

Answer (score 2):

You can open it...

```
with open('dane.txt', 'r') as file:
    ...
```

...then (into the `with`/`as` block) read the file...

```
content = file.read()
```

...then split it into a list:

```
myList = content.split('\n')
```